# Merge two api's

Tags: java, spring

How can I merge two external API's that have different input parameters and output values? They want the new merged controller to be backwards compatible. I'm not convinced it's possible looking at the existing code. I think someone is going to have to change inputs and results

```
package package1

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class SearchController {
    public ResponseEntity<String> request(@RequestBody String jsonSearch) {
        Search1 search = gson.fromJson(jsonSearch, Search1.class);
        List<Result1> results = search(search);
        return renderSuccess(results);
    }

    public static List<Result1> search(Search1 search) {....}

}

public class Search1 {
    private Calendar date;
    private Foo foo
}

public class Result1 {
    private Bar foo;
}

package package2

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class SearchRestful {
    public ResponseEntity<Bar> request(@RequestBody String jsonSearch2, @RequestParam(value = "limit") int limit) {
        Search2 search2 = gson.fromJson(jsonSearch2, Search2.class);
        Search1 search1 = transform(search2);
        // Yes it really calls the search in the other package
        List<Result1> results = SearchController.search(search1);
        List<Result2> results2 = transformResults(results);
        List<Result2> filteredResults2 = filter(results2, limit);
        return renderSuccess(filteredResults2);
    }
}

public class Search2 {
    private Date date;
    private String foo
}

public class Result2 {
    private Foo foo;
}
```

I need to create a new Controller in a different package

```
package package3

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class SearchController {
    // ?????
}
```

I'm supposed to do this for about 8 different controllers with multiple methods. Any ideas on how to merge and keep backwards compatability? They want to deprecate the old ones and start using the new combined ones. It's only used by applications created by my company, no external client apps currently use the api but I believe they want to which is why they want it cleaned up.

I told my boss we should create a new one that fixes all the weird things that were done in both but not try to make package3 backwards compatible for both. Deprecate the package1 and package2 (keep it but no more updates) and tell people if they want changes they have to move to package3 and only let new apps connect to package3.

Comment: You'd need to evaluate your incoming arguments and use some heuristics to determine which version of the API is being requested if it's not feasible to modify the client applications to use a prefix such as `foo.biz/api/v1/...`

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep the old ones as is, and add new Controllers with different endpoints.

EDIT: You can merge the two methods by setting the parameter limit as not required and type it with boxed integer:

> @RequestParam(value = "limit", required=false) Integer limit

This way, you can check whenever the limit is set, if yes, then SearchRestful, otherwise SearchController behavior. But god, this code is really crap and needs a good refactor. :(